# Sending Mass email

Tags: email, campaign

I have 1003 contacts in my org and I want to send them all an email.
I'm limited to 250 contacts per mass email, so I would like to create lists that would split my contacts (and future contacts) to groups, lets say based on the first letter of the Last Name.
So for example A-F, G-L, etc...

The problem is that the filter in the mass email contacts only supports AND and not OR.
The campaign filter is the same.

Any suggestion how I can solve this and create lists that include about 200 contacts each so they'll be ready for new contacts that are added with time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- as per [Mike's comment](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3369/sending-mass-email#comment3988_3372) to my first answer:

Create a Formula Custom Field

```
IF(
 OR( 
 BEGINS( LastName , "A"), 
 BEGINS( LastName , "B"), 
 BEGINS( LastName , "C"), 
 BEGINS( LastName , "D"), 
 BEGINS( LastName , "E"), 
 BEGINS( LastName , "F") 
 ), "A-F", 
IF(
 OR( 
 BEGINS( LastName , "G"), 
 BEGINS( LastName , "H"), 
 BEGINS( LastName , "I"), 
 BEGINS( LastName , "J"), 
 BEGINS( LastName , "K"), 
 BEGINS( LastName , "L") 
 ), "G-L", 
IF(
 OR( 
 BEGINS( LastName , "M"), 
 BEGINS( LastName , "N"), 
 BEGINS( LastName , "O"), 
 BEGINS( LastName , "P"), 
 BEGINS( LastName , "Q"), 
 BEGINS( LastName , "R"), 
 BEGINS( LastName , "S") 
 ), "M-S", 
"T-Z"
)))
```

You can set the mass email views according to this field.

Comment: Great idea! I implemented it and it works like a charm. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Create a new Pick List custom field on the contact object, where the values of it are:

[image]

- You might want to create a workflow/after trigger - that sets the value of this field according to the name.
- The rule criteria is:

[image]

[image]

The group will be set automatically.

Comment: To make it mandatory, why not do a formula field instead? It could examine the first letter of the last name and provide the grouping that way.

Comment: Love your idea better - stole it ^^